# Yet another inverse function to calculate

Tags: inverse

Is it possible to evaluate the inverse of this function, in order to obtain for each $y\in\mathbb R^+$ an explicit value of $f^{-1}(y)$? Thanks in advance!

$f(\delta)=(\frac{1}{Z})\delta^{-\alpha}e^{-\beta d\delta}$

[Function from  [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~lars/kdd08.pdf) article, page 8, item n°4]

Comment: Is $Z$ constant, i.e, *not* a function of $\delta$?

Comment: Yes, it is a constant!

Comment: You could try expressing $\delta^{-\alpha}$ as $e^{-\alpha\ln(\delta)}$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've tried that way... I obtained:
$-\alpha \log\delta -\beta d\delta=\log(f(\delta)Z)$, but I cannot ``collect'' $\log\delta$ with $\delta$... :|

Comment: Maybe it isn't possible to obtain an explicit inverse in this case. You *could* get an asymptotic approximation around $\delta=1$ if that helps.

Comment: Is there a method by which I could approximate that function? I don't need to obtain explicit values... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Near $\delta=1$, you can write $\log(\delta)\approx \delta - 1$. This is a *very crude* approximation, which you can imporve my adding more terms. See here for [more terms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+log(x)+around+x%3D1)

Comment: Since $f(\delta)=y$ is a probability function and $\delta$ is a positive time, $f^{-1}(y)=\delta$ could be potentially greater than 1. Is that crude approximation by Taylor expansion good even for $\delta>1$?

Comment: sadly, no it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the inverse function theorem, a function has an inverse in an interval $(a-c,a+c)$, if it is continuously differentiable at $a$.

We take the $\delta$ derivative to obtain $f'(\delta)=-\frac{\alpha}{z}\delta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta d\delta}-\frac{\beta d}{z}\delta^{-\alpha}e^{-\beta d\delta}$, and $f'(1)=-\frac{\alpha}{z}e^{-\beta d}-\frac{\beta d}{z}e^{-\beta d}\neq0$, so it has an inverse in a neighbourhood of $1$.

And in fact the derivative is nonzero $\forall y\in\mathbb{R^+}$, so we need not even restrict to a neighbourhood of $1$.

Following up the other post we have:

$$\frac{1}{z}(-\beta d-\alpha f^{-1}(\delta))\delta(f^{-1})'(\delta)=1$$

Let $g(\delta)=f^{-1}(\delta)$, and we have:

$$\int(-\beta d-\alpha g(\delta))dg(\delta)=\int \frac{z}{\delta}d\delta$$

$$\Rightarrow \left(-\beta d g(\delta)-\frac{\alpha}{2\delta}g(\delta)^2\right)=z\ln(\delta)+C\Rightarrow \left(\beta d g(\delta)+\frac{\alpha}{2\delta}g(\delta)^2\right)+z\ln(\delta)+C=0$$

Thus: $$g(\delta)=f^{-1}(\delta)=\frac{-\beta d\pm\sqrt{\beta\delta-2\frac{\alpha}{\delta}(\ln(\delta)+C)}}{\frac{\alpha}{\delta}}$$

Comment: the problem is not with showing the inverse exists, it is with *finding* an explicit inverse.

Comment: Hopefully my edit sorts things out.

Comment: (+1)yes it does. I edited the $\rm \TeX$ to make it more readable.

Comment: No worries, hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Lambert function : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function
The inverse you're looking for is closely related to the Lambert function.
However, it does not help much in general computations

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that function... Anyway, it doesn't help to compute a given value in output.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive $f$, you'll get:

$f'(\delta)=(\frac{1}{Z})(-\beta d -\alpha\delta ) f(\delta)$

Using it:

$f(f^{-1}(\delta)) = \delta$

$f'(f^{-1}(\delta)) * (f^{-1})'(\delta) = 1$

$(\frac{1}{Z})(-\beta d -\alpha f^{-1}(\delta) ) *\delta * (f^{-1})'(\delta) = 1$

Maybe you can take it from here to solve this equation